# Group items in list by size and multiples

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to automate something we do at work. I get a list of 20+ organizations and he number of guests they have. I then assign them table numbers. Each table holds eight people. So first I assign companies that are multiples of eight, then I start grouping the rest based off size.

Conceptually how do I do this. My initial thought is to create an array that has org name and size. Then add a column with the MOD of the 8. Then doing a for each item in the array that has a mod 1 and find if there is one with a mod 7. Except I don't know how to compare them, and am fuzzy removing them from an array, I spent all my time in SQL and rarely use arrays. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: Hack them into groups of 8 or less, and then you'll just have to solve the [Bin Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Not trivial ;)

Comment: use [array_chunck](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important for users to note the complexity of some requests. Had I not enjoyed this particular exercise, I wouldn't have taken the time to throw this together.

Assuming you have a data array like so:

```
<?php
$companies = array(  
  'Verizon' => 75,  
  'GE' => 42,
  'JP Morgan' => 38,
  'ATT' => 38,
  'Chevy' => 11,
  'Gray' => 4,
  'Individuals' => 0
);
?>
```

You would execute this script:

```
<?php function completeList($companies,$table_size){echo "<table>\n";echo "<tr><th>Company</th><th>Total</th></tr>\n";foreach($companies as $c=>$q){echo "<tr><td>$c</td><td>$q</td></tr>\n";}echo "</table>\n\n";fullTables($companies,$table_size);}function fullTables($companies,$table_size){$straglers=array();$extras=0;echo "<table>\n";echo "<tr><th>Company</th><th>FullTables</th><th>Extras</th></tr>\n";foreach($companies as $name=>$qty){echo "<tr><td>$name</td>";$tables=$qty/$table_size;if(!strpos($tables,'.'))$tables=number_format($tables,1);$totals=explode('.',$tables);$extras=$qty;if($qty>1)$extras=(intval($totals[1])/100)*$table_size;if($extras>$table_size&&$qty>=$table_size)$extras=$extras/10;if($extras<1&&$extras!=0)$extras=$extras*10;if($qty<=$table_size)$extras=$qty/1;echo "<td>$totals[0]</td><td>{$extras}</td>";$straglers[$name]=$extras;echo "</tr>\n";}echo "</table>\n\n";mixRemaining($companies,$straglers,$table_size);}function mixRemaining($companies,$straglers,$table_size){$assoc=array();$numeric=array();foreach($straglers as $c=>$q){array_push($assoc,$c);array_push($numeric,$q);}$i=0;$l=count($straglers);$jokers=0;$individuals=0;echo "<table>\n";echo "<tr><th>Companies</th><th>Grouped</th><th>Supply</th></tr>\n";while($i<$l){if($i!=$l-1&&$numeric[$i]>0){$members=$numeric[$i]+$numeric[$i+1];if($members>$table_size){$jokers=$members-$table_size;$remainder=$numeric[$i+1]-$jokers;$members=$numeric[$i]+$remainder;}else{$spaces_left=$table_size-$members;$jokers=0;}$mingled="$assoc[$i] and {$assoc[$i+1]}";echo "<tr><td>$mingled</td>";echo "<td>($numeric[$i]+{$numeric[$i+1]})$members</td>";if($jokers){echo "<td class=\"open\">$jokers extra {$assoc[$i+1]} members</td>";}else echo "<td class=\"over\">$spaces_left  spaces left</td>";if($jokers&&$i===($l-1))echo "<td>[+$jokersextra{$assoc[$i+1]}member(s)inlasttable.]</td>";$i++;echo "</tr>\n";}else{($jokers>0)?$final="$jokers extra people.":$final='all tables full!';break;}}echo "</table>\n\n";summary($companies,$straglers,$table_size,$final);}function summary($companies,$straglers,$table_size,$final){$total_companies=count($companies);$total_people=array_sum($companies);$total_tables=$total_people/$table_size;echo "<h4 id=\"summary\">$total_companies companies with $total_people people using $total_tables tables leaving $final</h4>\n";} ?>
```

By calling it with `completeList($companies,8);`, where `8` is the maximum table capacity:

```
<div id="table-table">
  <h4>Assuming you have a maxium capacity of 8 per table:</h4>
    <?php completeList($companies,8); ?>
</div>
```

I threw in some style for style. You can see a sample of the output [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4PXtm/).

The only thing I couldn't figure out is *where's that cookie at?*

Good luck! It was actually a fairly complicated script, but it seems to work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$companies = array(
  'GE' => 42,
  'ATT' => 38,
  'Chevy' => 11
);

foreach($companies as $name => $qty){
  echo "$name: \n";
  $tables = $qty/8;
  $totals = explode('.',$tables);
  $extras = (intval($totals[1])/100)*8;
  if($extras>8) $extras = $extras/10;
  echo "$totals[0] plus {$extras} extra. <br>\n";
}

?>
```

GE: 5 plus 2 extra.

ATT: 4 plus 6 extra.

Chevy: 1 plus 3 extra.

Now I guess the only question is *where's my damn cookie*. :)

Comment: This is the beginning, but not where my difficulty comes from.  With this method GE is using 6 tables, ATT has 5, and Chevy has 2 tables, for a total of 13 tables.  I need to make it where GE and ATT share a table because 2 extra and 6 extra would fill a table, this way there is a total of 11 full tables and 3 extra peeps at the twelfth table.

Comment: @user1895399 Seriously? I give you this from 0 posted code and you want me to wash your car too? C'mon. Alright alright, but if you get rich off this, I want my royalty checks haha.